# How to write pyspark dataframe to redshift database

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift

I am new in Redshift so I need some help with it.
I am trying to write pyspark dataframe with jdbc library (Not databricks one as this library is not valid for scala 2.12) to database but I am getting permissions error.
code:

```py
df.write.format('jdbc').options(
    url='jdbc:redshift://server:5439/db',
    driver='com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver',
    dbtable=new_table,
    user='user',
    password='pass').mode('append').save()
```

Error:

```
21/02/24 08:42:42 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redshift_spark.py", line 77, in <module>
   .mode('append').save()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 825, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, ip-192-168-1-132.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor driver): java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: The session is read-only;
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(Unknown Source)
```

Seems that I don't have reading permissions, but where do I need this permissions? I try to access to db using postgres library `psycopg2` and postgres jdbc driver `org.postgresql.Driver` and I have not problem.

Comment: It seems you have the read permission but the issue is on the write permission. You are calling the `write` function for your `df` which requires write permission on the destination side. In your case, you need the write permission in `redshift`. Please check the `user` permissions on AWS

Comment: Hi Amir, thanks for your quick response. I can write to redshift using postgres driver with same user. CAn it be that redshift driver needs access to cluster server?